# How to disable a ShellContent button

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a brand new Xamarin Shell application.  I just want to disable one of the buttons in the TabBar section.  I see there is an IsEnabled property but even if I set it to False, the button is still clickable and the view becomes visible.

```
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Title="Home" Route="HomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"/>
    <ShellContent Title="Settings" Route="SettingsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SettingsPage}" IsEnabled="False" />
</TabBar>
```

Is it not possible to disable the buttons that appear in the lower navigation of a Xamarin.Forms application?  I was hoping to disable certain buttons when conditions weren't met and enable them using event listeners.

Comment: Approach #1: Wrap the ShellContent in a `ShellSection`. IsEnabled should work on a section. Approach #2: [Dynamically Add/Remove `ShellContent`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cff82da-0c9c-429a-a3e0-23b0af8266d4/how-does-one-disable-a-shellcontent-in-a-shellsection-using-shell-in-xamarinforms?forum=xamarinforms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe @ToolmakerSteve's comments would work, what I ended up doing was putting each ShellContent in its own Tab:

```
<TabBar>
  <Tab>
    <ShellContent Title="Home" Route="HomePage" ConentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"/>
  </Tab>
  <Tab>
    <ShellContent Title="Settings" Route="SettingsPage" ContentTemplate="{Data Template local:SettingsPage}" IsEnabled="False" />
  </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Then I subscribed to events in the ShellContent class and enabled / disabled the Settings button at will.